# Trying to scrape Flight Data from Booking

Tags: python, booking.com-api

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?ss=London&ssne=London&ssne_untouched=London&label=gog235jc-1DCAEoggI46AdICVgDaFCIAQGYAQm4ARfIAQzYAQPoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4ArDuuaEGwAIB0gIkZmJhYjE4YzAtNDdhMy00MmY1LTk2NWItN2UzOTgyNTk1OWEx2AIE4AIB&aid=397594&lang=en-us&sb=1&src_elem=sb&src=searchresults&dest_id=-2601889&dest_type=city&checkin=2023-05-06&checkout=2023-05-07&ltfd=6%3A1%3A5-2023%3A&group_adults=2&no_rooms=1&group_children=0&sb_travel_purpose=leisure&selected_currency=USD&soz=1&lang_changed=1'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'
}

response  = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Find all the hotel elements in the HTML document
hotels = soup.findAll('div', {'data-testid': 'property-card'})

hotels_data = []
# Loop over the hotel elements and extract the desired data
for hotel in hotels:
    # Extract the hotel name
    name_element = hotel.find('div', {'data-testid': 'title'})
    name = name_element.text.strip()

    # Extract the hotel location
    location_element = hotel.find('span', {'data-testid': 'address'})
    location = location_element.text.strip()

    # Extract the hotel price
    price_element = hotel.find('span', {'data-testid': 'price-and-discounted-price'})
    price = price_element.text.strip()

    # Extract the hotel rating
    rating_element = hotel.find('div', {'class': 'b5cd09854e d10a6220b4'})
    rating = rating_element.text.strip()

    # Append hotes_data with info about hotel
    hotels_data.append({
        'name': name,
        'location': location,
        'price': price,
        'rating': rating
    })

    hotels = pd.DataFrame(hotels_data)
    hotels.head()

    hotels.to_csv('hotels.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

I am trying to scrape hotel details from booking.com, but it is showing the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\loxku\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\main24.py", line 31, in <module>
    price = price_element.text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

It shows the results only for hotel name and address but not the price of the hotel, Please help also obtain results for the hotel price and rating.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks In addition - In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)